# How to let a sidebar execute javascript code from the main document?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, sidebar

I'm working on a firefox sidebar that loads a webpage in the main document.
Now i'd like to call a javascript function from the main document in response of a pushed button on the sidebar.
How can the sidebar cause the main document to execute one of its javascript functions?
So far, I'm having a variable containing the javascript code, but how can it be executed? (in the context of the loaded website?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dr.Molle is correct with his answer but I always love working examples.

```
console.log("Opening new page at http://example.com");
page = window.open('http://example.com');
console.log(page);
console.log("calling alert on opened page");
page.alert("I opened and the previous windows JS called me!!!!");
console.log("called alert");
```

Example page => [Removed. See update below]

**Results:**

[image: alert initiated from other page]
[image: console logs]

**Note:** 
I had to allow popups for the demo code to work but that is another issue for another SO question. ; )

[image: firefox popup blocked notice]

**UPDATE:**

So doing

```
page.alert()
```

worked because it didn't have to wait for the page to finish loading for it to work. In order to be able to call a function is a script on the loaded page you have to ensure that the script has finished loading. To do illustrate this I changed my example.

Example page => http://mikegrace.s3.amazonaws.com/forums/stack-overflow/example-call-function-in-opened-page.html

The JS looks like this

```
page = window.open('http://mikegrace.s3.amazonaws.com/forums/stack-overflow/example-the-other-page.html');

var initOtherPage = function() {
  try {
    page.showMeTheMoney();
    console.log("It worked!");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("failed to call function on other page because: "+e);
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("trying again")
      initOtherPage();
    }, 1000);
  }
}
initOtherPage();
```

Console output

[image]

Opened page

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, page.alert() works, but how can a function thats inside an external script be called?
For example: 
The external script is included by:
<script src="/otherscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
otherscript.js contains a function i'd like to call. 
How can a function in otherscript.js be referenced/called? (typeof mainWindow[functionName] returns 'undefined' in this case).

Comment: @Nanadada, interesting. Not sure why. I'll have to check that out. Thanks for checking that.

Answer (score 3):

Load the page using window.open() and save it into a variable:

```
page=window.open('some.htm')
```

then you can access the window using this variable and call functions inside:

```
page.someFunction()
```